# Error in POM file while creating Spring Starter Project

Tags: spring-boot

I have just created a new Spring Starter Project in STS. After creating, seen it is not getting fully loaded as MAVEN project. Seen the below error in POM file.

Project build error: Non-parseable POM C:\Users\salim.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-
 parent\2.3.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-parent-2.3.0.RELEASE.pom: unexpected markup \n

Not sure what is happening. Please help me with this.

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.3.0.RELEASE
         
    
    com.vishnu.ws.soap
    hellowebservice
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    hellowebservice
    Hello SOAP Service

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: please update the question with your pom.xml

Comment: Where is the `<parent>` tag?

Comment: If you was used older version from spring, try to remove spring jars from m2 (Delete directory). I think it will help if your pom is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you posted your pom correctly, but it seems to be incorrect, therefore giving the parse error. It's missing some tags apprentely. IT should be something like this for your case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.vishnu.ws.soap</groupId>
    <artifactId>hellowebservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hellowebservice</name>
    <description>SOAP Service</description>

   <!-- additional lines as you have it now -->

 </project>
```